# Aligning .tikz pgfplots with semi custom styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, vertical-alignment

Previously I was helped with how to align and position graphs in a table with optional subplots in this question: [Overlay two .tikz files from input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164842/overlay-two-tikz-files-from-input)

It worked great, but I was not happy using scaling options to shrink the graphs. I much prefer just specifying the width and height, and letting latex take care of the font sizing. It made for a much more consistent article.

So when creating a graph I give it a style that allows a batch width and height setting in the preamble, and then edit the individual entries pertinent to that graph underneath.

Unfortunately using this system has thrown out alignment again. It seems alignment only remains when I either use a custom style that defines ALL the entries in the preamble, or when I don't use a custom style at all and set the width and height in the .tikz picture to be the same.

Full MWE to show my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,booktabs,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{inTable/.style={
width=4.0cm,
height=4.0cm,
}}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[inTable,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=500,
xlabel={A},
ymin=0.5,
ymax=1,
ylabel={A}]

\addplot [color=blue,solid,line width=1.0pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
10  0.7  \\
11  0.7  \\
12  0.7  \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newsavebox{\myboxB}
\sbox{\myboxB}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[inTable,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=200,
xlabel={B},
ymin=0,
ymax=3,
ylabel={B}]

\addplot [color=blue,solid,line width=1.0pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
10  0.5  \\
11  0.6  \\
12  0.7  \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{table}[htb!]
 \centering
     \begin{tabular}{P{6.5cm} P{6.5cm}}
     \toprule
      Expt1 & Expt2\\
      \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]
      \node[outer sep=0pt]  (a){\usebox{\mybox}};
       %%% Change dimensions in $(a.east)+(-0.9,0cm)$
%      \node[anchor=east,outer sep=0pt] at
%               ($(a.east)+(-0.9,0cm)$){\usebox{\mybox}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      {\usebox{\mybox}}
      &
      {\usebox{\mybox}}
      {\usebox{\myboxB}}
      \\ \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Test}
      \label{tbl:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Misalignment]

Help is greatly appreciated. This should be the final piece to my table-graph-inset plotting protocol.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you are trying to do with the `tabular` environment. For instance add a trailing `%` to line 67 and see what happens. So change line 67 to `\end{tikzpicture}%`.

Comment: Hi, The .tikz pictures are being organized in a table so I can align them under columns with the headings. I tried what you mentioned and it flips the bottom left graphs way out of position.

Comment: The problem here is caused by the differences of the `ticklabels` I'd say, which makes the width of the `tikzpicture`s different. I don't have any good ideas, but there are a couple of chapters in `pgfplots`' manual about aligning different plots, 4.19 and 4.20, have you looked at those? Edit: Adding an `\fbox` around each plot sort of illustrates this: http://i.imgur.com/j2i6vYl.png

Answer (score 1):

Okay, thanks Torbjørn T, the manual jolted my memory.

Firstly since the top left picture was actually a `{tikzpicture}` inside a `\begin{tikzpicture}` environment. I had to do the same thing for the top right picture. Then adding the alignment flags `[baseline, trim axis left, trim axis right]` to each `\begin{tikzpicture}` (the ones that I import from a .tikz file in my actual document, fixes the alignment.

Finally I have a method for total alignment and control of plots and subplots. Thanks to everyone that helped me.

Full MEW:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,booktabs,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{inTable/.style={
width=4.0cm,
height=4.0cm, %Change these numbers to ovveride all graphs in the table sizes in the table
}}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[inTable,
scale only axis,
baseline,
xmin=1,
xmax=500,
xlabel={A},
ymin=0.5,
ymax=1,
ylabel={A}]

\addplot [color=blue,solid,line width=1.0pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
10  0.7  \\
11  0.7  \\
12  0.7  \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newsavebox{\myboxB}
\sbox{\myboxB}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[inTable,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=200,
xlabel={B},
ymin=0,
ymax=3,
ylabel={B}]

\addplot [color=blue,solid,line width=1.0pt,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{
10  0.5  \\
11  0.6  \\
12  0.7  \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{table}[htb!]
 \centering
     \begin{tabular}{P{6.5cm} P{6.5cm}}
     \toprule
      Expt1 & Expt2\\
      \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]
      \node[outer sep=0pt]  (a){\usebox{\mybox}};
       %%% Change dimensions in $(a.east)+(-0.9,0cm)$
%      \node[anchor=east,outer sep=0pt] at
%               ($(a.east)+(-0.9,0cm)$){\usebox{\mybox}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      {\usebox{\mybox}}
      &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]
      \node[outer sep=0pt]  (a){\usebox{\mybox}};
       %%% Change dimensions in $(a.east)+(-0.9,0cm)$
%      \node[anchor=east,outer sep=0pt] at
%               ($(a.east)+(-0.9,0cm)$){\usebox{\mybox}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      {\usebox{\myboxB}}
      \\ \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Test}
      \label{tbl:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```